# Finding white ball using iPhone app using open CV

Tags: ios, iphone, opencv

My goal is to find white ball.
 Still now what i did:

1. First try to find white colour inside the cam are feed.
2. Try to find circle,semicircle and ellipses.
3. play sound once found half circle and circle.

Comment: you may need contrast stretching..

Comment: Thanks C.Canberk for your reply, can you provide more details ?

Comment: well...took me some time to find the golf ball in the image, how should a computer be able to do it if the object doesn't differ much from it's background?

Answer (score 1):

Well you need a dark background assumption to properly detect a white object.. "Histogram equalization" or "contrast stretching" might do the job too.. Google these with "opencv" tag.

Also you can use "circularity check" for detected contours. i.e. filter out contours having `(4*pi*area) / (perimeter*perimeter)` lower than `0.85`. You already filtered out small and non-convex ones, so this enhancement should work well.

You should also apply edge detection before hough transform for its best results.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I have done 3 changes which helps to remove unwanted circle.
cvEqualizeHist(imgRGBNew, imgRGB);
 cv::Canny(matThreshed, matThreshed, 255, 255);
   if (std::abs(1 - ((double)r.width / r.height)) <= 0.2 &&
                        std::abs(1 - (area / (CV_PI * std::pow(radius, 2)))) <= 0.2){
                        drawContours(matRGB, contours, 0, Scalar(255, 0, 0),3);
}
This solutions working fine for 5feet only but i want to implement this solution for 20-30 feet and for half circle as well to rid of golf ball is partially seen/hidden,due u have any clue on this?

Comment: well you can use shape matching (matchShapes) after defining a half circle. i.e. declare a vector of points data representing a half circle -declare it by hand- and use the method. the method is scale and rotation invariant so it should work well.

Comment: 30 feet= 9 meters. what is the resolution of your camera? a golf ball can be represented by only a single pixel at that range.. even if you zoom in somehow (sample up & de-noise) you will lose many info + false positives will occur

Comment: since findContours does not give correct output,I want to achieve some steps which i did with photoshop in opencv on image/live video frame
- start with the original picture
- then boost the satturation to get color into light areas
- the use curves to cut off the edges of the spectrum
- then convert the image to grayscale
- use curves again to get to black/white
- and finally - just for the look - apply a color